# New line character causing words to break up during text cleaning

Tags: python, python-3.x, whitespace, data-cleaning, removing-whitespace

I am trying to **clean some text** for further use using **Python**. Below is an example input text:

`have agreed in-\nsured as\nan per-\nson in\nwriting in a contract or agreement`

Now I want the output to be:

`have agreed insured as an person in writing in a contract or agreement`

But the **white space are causing problems**. I tried two different logic to achieve the desired output but **one works for certain words** and **not for others** and the **second works for certain and not for others**.

These are the two logic I have tried:-

**Logic 1:-**

x = "have agreed in-\nsured as\nan per-\nson in\nwriting in a contract or agreement"

```
#remove everything except alphabets and whitespaces
v = re.sub(r"[^\w\s.?!]", "", v)
#remove single whitespaces
v = v.replace("\n", "")
#remove extra whitespaces
v = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", v, flags=re.I)
```

This results in the following output:

`have agreed insured asan person inwriting in a contract or agreement`

As you can see the words `in-\nsured`, `per-\nson` have been cleaned properly but the words `as\nan` and `in\nwriting` have not been cleaned. So to solve this I tried the below logic:

**Logic 2:-**

```
v = re.sub(r"[^\w\s.?!]", "", v)    
v = v.replace("\n", " ")     <----This line has been changed (" " instead of "")
v = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", v, flags=re.I)
```

This gave the following output:

`have agreed in sured as an per son in writing in a contract or agreement`

The words `as\nan` and `in\nwriting` have been cleaned but this messes up the `in-\nsured` and `per-\nson`words.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty easy with simple string replacement. A hyphen followed by a newline is a single word, so just remove those. Then any other remaining newlines can get replaced by spaces. Thus:

```
s = 'have agreed in-\nsured as\nan per-\nson in\nwriting in a contract or agreement'
fixed = s.replace('-\n', '').replace('\n', ' ')
# 'have agreed insured as an person in writing in a contract or agreement'
```

Comment: Simple as that! Now I feel dumbXD!